# apache web server does not start in XAMPP 7.0.13-0 in OSX

Tags: apache

I have installed XAMPP 7.0.13-0 but when I try to star Apache Web Server it starts but then stops and in the Application log only see this: 
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started

Any error but the status column of Apache Web Server says that is stopped and looks in red.

I have all the default ports: 80 and 443
I have MAMP too installed but with all the services stopped

Any idea please...

Regards

Comment: Hi, http://serverfault.com/ might be a better resource for you. SO is more for programming errors.

Comment: Not sure how OSX does it, but my guess would be the ports are locked because you have MAMP already. Try editing the Apache conf and tell it to listen on another port, like 8000, 8080, etc.